# pandas dataframe - Get value from under certain criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
print df
   id  product_id   product_title     search_term  relevance
0   2      100001  Simpsom Strong    anglebracket       3.00
1   3      100001  Simpsom Strong        ibracket       2.50
2  16      100005      Delta Vero  rainshowerhead       2.33
```

Let's say I have id = 3 and want the search_term associated with it (VALUE ONLY). How would I extract that?

It got answer code of:

```
target = df.loc[df['id']==3, 'search_term']
print target
```

However, it returns a entire pandas series including index like:

```
1    ibracket
Name: search_term, dtype: object
```

not the value only 'ibracket'.

I know I can get the value by doing:

```
target_i = df.loc[df['id']==16, 'search_term'].index[0]
target = df ['search_term'] [target_i]
```

so I can get what I want as the value only.  But I assume there should be a way more like:

```
target = df.loc[df['id']==16, 'search_term'].value
```

and get the value only directly.

But this doesn't work, does anyone know a solution to this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Request : Can you give the code to create the df? print(df) shows us the dataframe but it's tough to follow through.

Answer (score 1):

If always matched at least one value and is necessary select first `search_term` select by position - [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) or convert value of Series to numpy array and select by indexing:

```
target_i = df.loc[df['id']==16, 'search_term'].iat[0]

target_i = df.loc[df['id']==16, 'search_term'].values[0]

#pandas 0.24+ solution
target_i = df.loc[df['id']==16, 'search_term'].to_numpy()[0]
```

If possible is returned empty Series it failed.

---

So general solution is `next` with `iter`:

```
target_i = newxt(iter(df.loc[df['id']==16, 'search_term']), 'no match')

target_i = newxt(iter(df.loc[df['id']==16000, 'search_term']), 'no match')
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.loc[df['id']==16, 'search_term']`

There can be multiple rows with `id==some_value` so the correct design is to return a series of matches rather then one value. This is the reason why you get a series not a single value.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it the long way. This works:

```
search_term = df.loc[df['id'] == 3, 'search_term'].iloc[0]
```

Any Series can have 0 to many elements. `iloc[0]` gets the value of the first element in that series. For production, you should check if the series is empty first.

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I wanted!